# Should rxjs subjects be public in the class?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

Let's say I have two classes, where you can observe over some observables.

First example, with public subject:

```
class EventsPub {
   public readonly onEnd = new Subject<void>();
}
```

Second example, with private subject and registering method:

```
class EventsPriv {
   private readonly endEvent = new Subject<void>();

   public onEnd(cb: () => void): Subscription {
       return this.endEvent.subscribe(cb);
   }
}
```

The first example is somehow unsafe because anyone can call `eventsPub.endEvent.next()` from outside the class and introduce side effects, however, comparing to example 2 It allows for pipes, which is a big plus since developers can for ex. register only for the first event with `eventsPub.onEnd.pipe(first()).subscribe(cb)`.

The second example also allows for one-time subscription but requires more code and ugly unsubscribing.

```
const subscription = eventsPriv.onEnd(() => {
    // logic..
    subscription.unsubscribe()
});
```

From your point of view, which is the best way to go? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is based a lot on my personal preference but I'd do it like this:

```
class EventsPriv {
   private readonly endEvent = new Subject<void>();

   get endEvent$(): Observable<void> {
      return this.endEvent;
   }
}
```

So inside the class I'll use `endEvent` while I can still use it eg. in a template with `obj.endEvent$ | async` and from the outside it behaves like an Observable.

Note, that in fact I'm returning the same instance of `Subject`. The only thing that restricts the outside world from misusing it with `obj.endEvent$.next()` are Typescript's type guards. If I was using just JavaScript or if I typecasted it to `any` I could call `next`.

This is actually the recommended way of exposing `Subject`s instead of using the `asObservable()` operator. You can notice that this is used everywhere internally in RxJS 5. For example if you look at `repeatWhen` synopsys:

```
public repeatWhen(notifier: function(notifications: Observable): Observable): Observable
```

You can see that the `notifier` function receives an Observable as a parameter (you can see it in the code here as well https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/operators/repeatWhen.ts#L29).

But if you look into the code where the function is called you'll see they are in fact passing a `Subject` and not an `Observable`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/operators/repeatWhen.ts#L114-L115.

This has been discussed on RxJS GitHub page and reasons for this are performance and that the Typescript type guards are sufficient. You can read more in these discussions:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2408
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2391